# How to return a custom array item from a class and manipulate its properties? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am trying to return a Cell array item from the Table class using a get function. The Cell class has its own set function.

I tried by just making a Cell array and getting and setting the attributes. It worked, but for some reason it doesn't work here.

```cpp
class Cell {
    int content;
    ...
public:
    Cell() {
        content = 0;
        ...
    }
    int getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    void setContent(int x){
        content = x;
    }
};

class Table {
    Cell cells[10];
public:
    Table() {}

    Cell getCell(int i) {
        return cells[i];
    }
};

int main () {
    Table t;
    t.getCell(0).setContent(22);
    std::cout<<t.getCell(0).getContent();
}
```

I was expecting to get 22 but the program outputs nothing.

Comment: `getCell` returns a copy. The cell you set 22 is not the same you later call `getContent`

Comment: How do I fix that?

Comment: read about references

Comment: What purpose does the `Table` class have beyond as a container for `Cell` objects? Could you solve your problem by having e.g. `std::array<Cell, 10>` (possibly as a type-alias named `Table`) instead of a dedicated `Table` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because here

```
Cell getCell(int i) {
    return cells[i];
}
```

You're returning a copy of the `Cell`. You then change its contents, but those are lost when the copy goes out of scope. `getCell(0)` makes a copy that is discarded at the end of this line. Instead you want to return a reference to the cell:

```
Cell& getCell(int i) {
```

Now it's changing the contents of the `Cell` in `cells[10]`, not a copy thereof.

Comment: I guess returning `Cell& ` is not safe, one can change it using move semantic outside of class

Comment: @Mayur huh? If it is `const` you wont be able to call `setContents` on it. I dont understand why you think it is not "safe", though I also dont understand why you want to write unnecessary boilerplate. What does your `Table` do that a `std::array` cant?

Comment: @user463035818 the reference is `const`, not the `Cell` itself. I also don't think that this table solution is very practical, I wanted to answer OP's question of why the change isn't persisted in his particular code. It seems like pass by copy/reference is confusing him, so I wanted to explain that in particular.

Comment: @user463035818 you're right. I removed it again. It worked on MSVC (but then again, that doesn't mean much...). Either way it now works https://onlinegdb.com/SkIxMRzh4 Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @user463035818  I was referring not safe as returning the reference of private member one can modify it outside of class. I am not sure it is fine to return reference of private member is ok in this case

Comment: @Mayur it has to be non-const otherwise you cannot modify it. Containers typically return non-const references to their elements. But you are right to have doubts. The thing is: Once you return a non-const reference to a member it is rather pointless to have the member private, you could make it public as well, and in your case I dont see any problem with that. encapsulation is not the holy grail, if you want to allow direct modification of `Cell`s from outside the `Table` there is no reason to make exactly that impossible

Answer (score 0):

You can try sth like this :

```
Cell* getCell(int i) {
   return &cells[i];
}


t.getCell(0)->setContent(22);
std::cout<<t.getCell(0)->getContent();
```